# continuous function in $(\mathbb{R} ^3,||\cdot||_\frac{3}{2})$

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Let $f:(\mathbb{R} ^3,||\cdot||_\frac{3}{2}) \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous function.

Prove that $A=[(x,y,z):f(x,y,z)<1]$ is open. Could someone give me a hint to start this one off?

I tried writing the f as the norm $< 1$ but it led me to even more confusion about the problem.

Comment: Could you define $\|\cdot\|_{3/2}$ please?

Comment: @Falcon yes it is $(|x_1|^{3/2} + |x_2|^{3/2} + |x_3|^{3/2})^{2/3}$ so in this case it is the $(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3} |x_n - y_n - z_n|^{3/2})^{2/3}$.

Comment: Ir is an open set as reciprocal image of the open set $(-\infty,1)$ by a continuous function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just the inverse image of $(-\infty,1)$ which is an open set in $\mathbb R$ under $f$.  The definition of continuous functions the inverse image of open sets are open

Comment: Well exactly that, but my proffesor decided to give me 5 exercises just switching up the norms and thats why i am questioning my existence at this point.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the norm is on the domain, the norm on the range is what matters here

Comment: could you please define "range" ?

Comment: The space you are mapping into,  which in this case is $\mathbb R$. I suppose technically I should have said codomain

Comment: sounds good thanks for the quick response.